# Linux - keyboard with phone-like typing

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, udev, phone

I have a USB keyboard extension with just number-keys: [image]

I need to write chars (A to Z) on this keyboard.

My idea is write the way you can on some phone keypads, where each number is mapped to several letters. 
[image]

In other words, if I press "1" twice, it writes A, two presses on "2" selects B, four presses on 9 represents Z. (See photo.  Each press moves to the next consecutive letter mapped to each key.)

Is this possible?

Comment: No way. Just buy a normal keyboard or use onboard screen keyboard.

Comment: Would be quite nice if this was possible... a new input method might have to developed or something. However, this is unlikely to happen as it would not have much use, as most modern devices uses keyboards/touchscreens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is use **multipress** input method.

In app is need to set multipress input method manually. If you want have multipress as default you need to create file `/.xinputrc` with content:

```
GTK_IM_MODULE=multipress
QT_IM_MODULE=multipress
```

Comment: Yes. And you'll probably have to redefine whole keyboard in `.xmodmap` file.